# Is there an include file for class statements in python?

Tags: python

I think this is almost certainly a very basic question but I'm struggling with it. I have 2 python files, one for the main content on my site and one for the admin area. You can see the two files here:

https://gist.github.com/670034

In both these files I define the classes and import the necessary modules at the top and if I change in one file I need to remember to change in the other file. Is there a way to define all these in one file and then include this for both files?

I'm sure there is an easy way of doing this but I can't seem to find how to do it.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a file, like `myimports.py`:

```
import cgi
import os

from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.datastore import entity_pb
```

Then you can do:

```
from myimports import *
```

Note that while this saves space, it doesn't make it more readable as you need to check the additional file just to see what you imported.

Comment: Thanks poke! This is exactly what I was looking for, I new it was simple but was struggling to get it nailed. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to be able to help. Btw. click the tick next to the answer to accept it as the answer of the question and mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing what poke says, it's maybe better not to make your imports in a centralised place as you can end up losing fine grained control over what is in your namespace. I know this does not answer your question, but it may help in the long run.

Comment: Hi Raz, can you explain a bit more why this method is not recommended? Seems like a no-brainer, just like putting your Google Analytics tags in a sitewide include file right? What control am I losing?

Comment: 'don't use import *' sounds easier to remember. And I explain it so: you want to know where objects come from, when you point the finger at them

Comment: Well, probably is a no brainer if your project only has a handful of files in it, but on a bigger project it can start to become difficult to keep track of what's being imported and hence possibly introducing errors which are hard to track down.

Comment: Thanks Raz - I think that makes sense. For my project I think it will simplify things but I can see how it might get out of control at some point! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create new module:

```
import some

class A:
   pass
```

and import module in the both files:

```
import new_module
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the classes in a separate file and `import` it in the other two.